# What really happens when you close an app on iOS/iPadOS and immediately reopen it?

Tags: ios, ipados

I want to know if there is an increased risk for soft errors to occur if I close an app and immediately reopen it. Does the system handle it like two different instances, as if I had closed one app and opened a different app? Or does some residue from the previous run cross over to the following launch?

Comment: How to you „close“ the app in this case? And which practical problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: iOS doesn't quit apps when you go back to the Home screen. They are usually retained in memory all the time.

Comment: Are you talking about force-quitting an app by dragging it out of the list of running apps? I'll bet anything iOS doesn't allow it to restart until it has been fully shut down.